# JSON Schema validator not loading

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

Need a JSON schema validator for user inputs. I'm planning to use https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
static JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
static {
        try {
            logger.info("Looking for schema");

            JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(JSONValidator.class
                    .getClassLoader()
                    .getResource("schema.json")
                    .toString());


        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse JSON Schema. Cannot validate JSON inputs ", e);
        }
    }
```

Get this exception even before reading the schema file. Tested it by removing all code and retaining only this line:

```
static JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
```

What could be wrong?

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.newMapper(JacksonUtils.java:155)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JacksonUtils.<clinit>(JacksonUtils.java:55)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.<init>(JsonNodeReader.java:82)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.<clinit>(JsonLoader.java:50)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<init>(SchemaVersion.java:63)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<clinit>(SchemaVersion.java:44)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfigurationBuilder.<init>(LoadingConfigurationBuilder.java:117)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfiguration.byDefault(LoadingConfiguration.java:151)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.<init>(JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.java:67)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder(JsonSchemaFactory.java:123)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(JsonSchemaFactory.java:113)
    at com.intuit.mumble.validator.JSONValidator.<clinit>(JSONValidator.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I know that something this JSON Schema Validator expecting in Jackson is not available.
But would like to know if you have encountered this issue with the version that you've used and resolved it already.

json.schema.validator.version 2.2.5
jackson2.version 2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading jackson version to 2.3.2